# Unable to import React component (Module not found Error)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babeljs, node-modules

I've installed a private GitHub repo into my React JS project using the git command:

```
npm i --save https://github.com/******/ui-infra.git#master
```

This is successfully installed in my React project and I can see inside **node_modules** folder. The imported repo contains all components (all these components are built using **TS** and **TSX**) I need to use in my new React Project which is basically a **JS** and **JSX** React project.

I tried to import one the component from ui-infra

```
    import { CalenderDatePicker } from "ui-infra/src/components/CalendarDatePicker/CalendarDatePicker";
    function App() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <CalenderDatePicker />
      </div>
     );
    }
```

But showing this error

```
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'ui-infra/src/components/CalendarDatePicker/CalendarDatePicker' in 'E:\*****\*****\frontend\src'
```

I tried with Just direct import as I can see Ui-infra in vs code path suggestion,

```
    import { CalenderDatePicker } from "ui-infra";

    ./src/App.js
    Module not found: Can't resolve 'ui-infra' in 'E:\RedMonk\Bizongo\frontend\src'
```

But still getting module not found error. Please help

**CalenderDatePicker.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { DatePicker } from "antd";
import moment from "moment";
import { CalendarDatePickerProps } from "./CalendarDatePicker.d";

const CalendarDatePicker: React.FC<CalendarDatePickerProps> = ({
  onChange,
  dateBefore,
  rangeOfDates,
  dateSet,
  dateAfter,
  daySet,
  ...props
}) => {
  var newDateSet = [];

  if (dateSet) {
    newDateSet = dateSet.slice(dateSet);
  }

  if (rangeOfDates) {
    for (let i = 0; i < rangeOfDates.length; i += 1) {
      for (
        let tempDate = moment(rangeOfDates[i].from);
        tempDate.diff(moment(rangeOfDates[i].to), "days") <= 0;
        tempDate.add(1, "days")
      ) {
        newDateSet.push(moment(tempDate));
      }
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < newDateSet.length; i++) {
    newDateSet[i] = moment(newDateSet[i]).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
  }

  const disabledDate = (current, dateBefore, dateAfter, daySet, newDateSet) => {
    return (
      current &&
      ((dateBefore && current < moment(dateBefore).startOf("day")) ||
        (dateAfter && current > moment(dateAfter).endOf("day")) ||
        (daySet && daySet.includes(current.format("dddd"))) ||
        (newDateSet && newDateSet.includes(current.format("DD/MM/YYYY"))))
    );
  };

  return (
    <DatePicker
      onChange={onChange}
      disabledDate={current =>
        disabledDate(current, dateBefore, dateAfter, daySet, newDateSet)
      }
      data-loc={"ui-infra-calendar-date-picker"}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};

CalendarDatePicker.displayName = "CalendarDatePicker";

export default CalendarDatePicker;
```

Comment: Check package.json file. You can find there valid path for import

Comment: "ui-infra": "github:*******/ui-infra#master", @captain-yossarian

Comment: So, try `import {CalendarDatePicker} from 'github:*******/ui-infra#master'`

Comment: Tried both ways

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46661726/webpack-cant-import-package-installed-from-git

Comment: Module not found error usually occurs when either your path is wrong or your component isn't exported properly/ doesn't exist. Is the component exported properly? Could you post the contents of the CalendarDatePicker file

Comment: Please check, I've added the code @BenzStevox

Comment: When a component is exported as default, you dont put it in braces.
So in your App.js import it as ` import CalenderDatePicker from "ui-infra/src/components/CalendarDatePicker/CalendarDatePicker";`

Comment: I tried with and without braces. Same error Only @BenzStevox

Comment: Did you npm install while the react start script was running? Sometimes it may fail to pick up new modules and you have to restart the script

Comment: If your other project is in tsx and this project isn't, then maybe there is no transpiled version and only the `.tsx` file is present which won't be found if your project isn't configured for TypeScript.

Comment: @MoritzMahringer How to fix this ? Can you please help me

Comment: The other project should transpile it's sources to plain js. Then the import should work. Without more info it's really hard to answer this.